Cannot start fail2ban on debian 12: Failed to initialize any backend for Jail 'sshd'
I cannot start fail2ban on a Debian 12 server. I get the following error:
2024-04-01 23:51:42,973 fail2ban                [16176]: ERROR   NOK: ("Failed to initialize any backend for Jail 'sshd'",)
2024-04-01 23:51:42,973 fail2ban.server         [16176]: INFO    Shutdown in progress...
2024-04-01 23:51:42,973 fail2ban.observer       [16176]: INFO    Observer stop ... try to end queue 5 seconds
2024-04-01 23:51:42,993 fail2ban.observer       [16176]: INFO    Observer stopped, 0 events remaining.
2024-04-01 23:51:43,033 fail2ban.server         [16176]: INFO    Stopping all jails
2024-04-01 23:51:43,034 fail2ban.database       [16176]: INFO    Connection to database closed.
2024-04-01 23:51:43,234 fail2ban.server         [16176]: INFO    Exiting Fail2ban

I know that sshd logs to systemd, and I have accordingly configured the jail for sshd:
[sshd]
backend = systemd
enabled = true
port    = ssh
logpath = %(sshd_log)s
maxretry = 3


I can't reproduce this error. If I drop your sshd jail into jail.local and run fail2ban-server -xf start, runs without any errors (whereas if I don't have that configuration, it fails because it can't find the sshd log).
